# Flutter: How to Refresh token when token expires during http call?

Tags: flutter, flutter-http

I am new to flutter and I am using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package for network call. I want to refresh token and call the request again if the response code of the request 200. How can I acheive this using http package? I heard about [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package but it is complicated for me.

```
User getUser(){

   final response = http.post(Uri.https(BASE_URL, '/api/user'), 
    headers: {'Authorization: Bearer $token'});

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
       return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)['user']);
    }
    else if(response.statusCode == 401){
      //refresh token and call getUser again     
    }

}
```

Comment: use interceptor to retry your request.
may this package helps you:- https://pub.dev/packages/http_interceptor

Comment: when the token expires, it should give a response code 401. In this case you can call a new function to get a fresh token and replace the old token with the response received.

Answer (score 23):

You can use refresh token as follows:

```
User getUser(){

   final response = http.post(Uri.https(BASE_URL, '/api/user'), 
    headers: {'Authorization: Bearer $token'});

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
       return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)['user']);
    }
    else if(response.statusCode == 401){
      //refresh token and call getUser again
      final response = http.post(Uri.https(BASE_URL, '/api/[YourAuthorizationEndpoint]'), 
    headers: {'grant_type': 'refresh_token', 'refresh_token': '$refresh_token'});
      token = jsonDecode(response.body)['token'];
      refresh_token = jsonDecode(response.body)['refresh_token'];
      return getUser();
    }

}
```

Comment: Error 401 is for Un-authorize, but it does not only means that the Token is expired. What if the Token is not expired BUT the user is not authorized to access the resources due to some other reasons? Then what strategy should be applied to know if 401 was returned due to Token expiry or some other reason?

Comment: You have access to the `response.body` so you can examine it to check the response. Then you would just modify the code to check for the body response criteria.

Comment: What about when the refresh endpoint also returns Unauthorized 401? that'll be an infinite loop

Answer (score 12):

You can use dart's `http/retry` package:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http_retry/http_retry.dart';

final client = RetryClient(
   http.Client(), 
   retries: 1,
   when: (response) {
    return response.statusCode == 401;
   },
   onRetry: (req, res, retryCount) {
     if (retryCount == 0 && res?.statusCode == 401) {
        // refresh token
     }  
   },
);

try {
  final response = await client.get('http://www.example.com');
} finally {
  client.close();
}
```

Comment: `return response.statusCode == 401 ? true : false` => `return response.statusCode == 401`...

Comment: Iam Trying this and the token is refreshed indeed, but the request itself is still using the old JWT and the response is still 401 as if it was the old request result and the JWT in the header value does not update....how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

call an api to refresh token after expiration

you can use this [package][1]

[1]: https://pub.dev/packages/jwt_decoder   to check if token is expired

you can also get the time since token created and date of expiration

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flutter [retry](https://pub.dev/packages/retry) package to do this.
You can refresh the access tokens on 401. Refresh means make a seperate API call to get the new access token from API and save it on the device. Then _getAccessToken() method read the access token from the device preferences and use it on the retry call.

```
RetryClient _getHttpClient() {
    return RetryClient(
      http.Client(),
      retries: 2,
      when: (response) {
        return response.statusCode == 401;
      },
      onRetry: (req, res, retryCount) async {
        if (res?.statusCode == 401) {
          await _authRepository.refreshTokens();

          // Remove old token
          req.headers.remove('Authorization');

          // add new token
          Map<String, String> tokenHeader = await _getAccessToken();
          req.headers.addEntries(tokenHeader.entries);
        }
      },
    );
  }

// Make API Call
final response = await _getHttpClient().post(
  apiPath,
  headers: headers,
  body: body,
);
```